# $\pi = 0\times\infty$

Tags: limits, pi

I found this equation online that lets you calculate $\pi$: “$\pi = x \times \sin(180/x)$”, where $x$ must be a “big”  number (close to infinity) so that it's as accurately close to $\pi$ as possible.

Since replacing $x$ with infinity would give us the exact value of $\pi$, I came to the following conclusion:

´´´

$\pi = \lim_{x\to\infty}x\times\sin(180/x)$

$\pi = \lim_{x\to\infty}x\times\sin(0)$

$\pi = \lim_{x\to\infty}0\times x$

´´´

But “$0 \times\infty$” is not defined, so are my calculations incorrect?

Comment: PS: Sorry for the formatting! If anyone is able to fix it I'd appreciate it!

Comment: When calculating limits, you don't just "plug in" infinity.

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) you can quickly learn how to format formulas.

Comment: Replacing $x$ by infinity doesn't give you anything at all.

Comment: On the other hand, for big values of $x$, we have $5 \approx x \times \frac{5}{x+7}$. Therefore $5 = \infty \times 0$. Since $\infty \times 0$ can have multiple values, it is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

You can not isolate limits.

You can not do $\lim_{x\rightarrow p} f(x)g(x) = \lim_{x\rightarrow p} [f(x)*\lim_{y\rightarrow p} g(y)]$.

That simply is not true and can not be done.

You can do $\lim_{x\rightarrow p}f(x)*g(x) = \lim_{x\rightarrow p}f(x)*\lim_{x\rightarrow p}g(x)$ but *only* if $ \lim_{x\rightarrow p}f(x) =A$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow p}g(x) = B$ and $A*B$ are all defined.  As $0*\infty$ is not defined we can not do it here.

Comment: I would like to add, that $A,B∈ℝ$ is important. The frequently used notation $\lim a_n = ∞$ is misleading¹. If $a_n→a$, with $a∈ℝ$, one says, that "the sequence $a_n$ converges to its limit $a$", and one can write $\lim a_n = a$.  But a sequence never converges to $∞$ - it diverges strictly. If you keep that in mind, you can't break the rule stated by @fleablood.  [Btw. that plays an important role in the construction of ℝ by Cauchy-sequences. Otherwise it would be $∞∈ℝ$. || ¹It is ok to use it though - since everyone 'knows' what it should mean.]

Comment: @P.Siehr I was deliberately avoiding that.  If the notation $\lim a_n = \infty$ is taken to mean ... what it usually does ... then indeed it *is* the case that if $\lim a_n = \infty$ and $\lim b_n = B>0$ or $\lim b_n = \infty$ then $\lim a_n*b_n =\infty$ and if you use the notation of $a > 0;$ or $a =\infty$ then define $a*\infty = \infty$ then we *can* say $\lim a_n*b_n = \lim a_n*\lim b_n$.  That that is *EXCEDINGLY* misleading and $\lim a_n = \infty$ does *not* mean there is a number called infinity.  It is notation for diverges strictly.